# ScatterPlot ng2-nvd3 big black circle

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular-nvd3, ng2-nvd3

I am using ng2-nvd3 to plot a scatter. I fetch the data and create the data object in the good format. Then I create the option to display the chart.
The points are properly displayed but I have big black circle instead of having normal circle. See the picture[image: pictureBigCircle]

And I would like to have this:
[image: pictureDesired]

I don't know where does it come from. My code in my component:
**To generate the data**

```
  generateData(groups, points) {
    let samples = points.sampleNames;
    points = points.pcaComponents;
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
      data.push({
        values: []
      });
      for (var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        data[i].values.push({
          x: points[j][0], //PC1
          y: points[j][1], // PC2
          label: samples[j],
          size: Math.random(),
          shape: "circle"
        });
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

**To generate the option**

```
scatterChart(pca) {
    return {
      chart: {
        type: "scatterChart",
        height: 450,
        color: d3.scale.category10().range(),
        interactive: true,
        showLegend: false,
        showLabels: false,
        scatter: {
          onlyCircles: false
        },
        showDistX: true,
        showDistY: true,
        duration: 350,
        xAxis: {
          axisLabel: "PC1 (" + pca.variance[0] + "%)",
          tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.format(".3g")(d);
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          axisLabel: "PC2 (" + pca.variance[1] + "%)",
          tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.format(".3g")(d);
          },
          axisLabelDistance: -5
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<nvd3 [options]="chart" [data]="data"></nvd3>
```

Comment: _"but I have big black circle instead of having normal circle“_ what makes you think big and black is abnormal?

Comment: Because this is not the plot expected if you look at the example. And furthermore, the first second I see the little blue circle and then the big black circle appears.

Comment: The style.css was missing

Comment: @PierBJX what style.css ? Where do you get it from?

Comment: https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3#component. @dKab, you will see that the styleUrls is included ;)

Comment: Strange that other types of charts don't require this css to be included...